Yeats refers to a common soul in the occult tradition. What might he be referring to?
Yeats takes for granted the conception of the destiny of the human soul that is “common to the occult tradition.  What is this destiny that occult traditions commonly agree the soul has?  And because "occult" is problematic, could I find a commonality with mysticism more generally?  What about Emerson's Oversoul?  The ideas of established religions would have to be here omitted, as not being occult, but I suppose there could be overlap.
Reference:  "'Everywhere that Antinomy between the One and the Many':  The Foundations of A Vision," by Neil Mann, page 1, contained in WB Yeats' A Vision:  Explications and Concepts, 2012.

A further important source of difficulty is that some of the concepts had much in common with those that Yeats had encountered in his esoteric apprenticeship. . .  Hough comments that “Yeats takes for granted the conception of the destiny of the human soul” that is “common to the occult tradition,” and Yeats wrote that A Vision was “intended . . . for my ‘schoolmates only’”. . . However, even for those who were “schoolmates,” more versed in the occult tradition than the general reader today, there were problems, as . . . the unspoken differences from tradition are potentially almost as much of a stumbling block as the unspoken common ground.


You have to search sources about Y and the occult tradition

The appearance of word "occult" in the question doesn't make it unphilosophical.  In the history of philosophy, distinctions were more blurred, e.g., links between philosophy and mysticism and religion, chemistry and alchemy, criticisms of Continental philosophy as being anti-rational, etc.  Not abandoning rational thought, suggesting Yeats arrives at conclusions similar to people we accept as philosophers, e.g., Kant.  You may not know muvh about Yeats, in which case, do what I do and eschew comment.  By this reasoning, questions about Eastern "philosophy" are, I assume, also unwelcome.
